# Insertar datos en un array JSON dentro de una instancia Winwheel (Ruleta) con javascript

Tags: javascript

Se está desarrollando una ruleta, el código funciona correctamente con código hardcodeado. A continuación pondré un fragmento de código:

```
var totalSponsors = '${sponsors.size()}';

    // Create new wheel object specifying the parameters at creation time.
    let theWheel = new Winwheel({
        'numSegments'  : totalSponsors,     // Specify number of segments.
        'outerRadius'  : 212,   // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
        'textFontSize' : 18,    // Set font size as desired.
        'segments'     :        // Define segments including colour and text.
        [
           {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 5'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 6'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 7'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 8'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 9'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 10'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 11'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 12'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 13'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 14'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 15'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 16'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 17'},
           {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 18'}

        ],
        'animation' :           // Specify the animation to use.
        {
            'type'     : 'spinToStop',
            'duration' : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
            'spins'    : totalSponsors,     // Number of complete spins.
            'callbackFinished' : alertPrize
        }
    });
    
    // Insert the sponsor name in the roulette
    <c:forEach items='${sponsors}' var="index" varStatus="status">
        //console.log("NAME: " + '${index.getSponsorName()}');
    </c:forEach>
```

Quiero insertar los datos de la lista "sponsors" (bucle forEach) en el campo "text" del array "segments". Los nombres de cada patrocinador se obtiene con la siguiente línea de código:

```
 '${index.getSponsorName()}'
```

El código de la ruleta se ha obtenido en el siguiente enlace:

> http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/examples/basic_code_wheel

Comment: Cuál es el problema, no termino de entender?

Comment: He podido insertar los datos en el array "segments" de json. La solución se puede ver en el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863260/insert-data-into-a-json-array-inside-a-winwheel-instance-roulette-with-javascr/68863611#